# How do I remove a Reader from my Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I accepted the Repo shown in the Reader category.  How do I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Accepting a shared code repository**

Repositories that you have been granted access to can be added to the Scripts tab by opening the Code Editor with the `accept_repo` URL parameter. For example:

```
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/USER_NAME/REPO_NAME
```

**Removing a shared code repository**

Repositories can be removed by clicking on the Hide button, which will appear to the right of the repository name when you roll your cursor over the name.

[image: Code Editor Script Tab showing the Hide button]